# Is there a way to add a login item in the terminal without triggering a permission dialog on macOS 10.14 and above?

Tags: macos, permission, automation

For context: I am working on a script whose purpose is to install a specific application and also add it to the user's login items. This program may need to be deployed to a large number of systems so it is desirable that it be installed without any user input on the target machine.

Currently this is being done via a command along the lines of `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to make login item ...'` which works fine in versions of macOS prior to 10.14. However, in more recent versions executing this command triggers a dialog requesting Automation (AppleEvents) permissions, which prevents the install from running unattended.

Is there either an alternate way to add a login item that does not require additional permissions, or else a way to grant the required permission without user input?

Comment: Playing devil’s advocate here: **What you’re doing is sneaky.** Users should, in general, know what software is installed and runs at login on their machines. While there is definitely a way to do this, and there are definitely legitimate use cases for it, what I would like to hear from you is your specific use case and why it is preferable for the user to be **unaware of** and **not provide their consent to** run software under their user account.

Comment: @pion: I appreciate your concern. The scenario is that a sysadmin for several thousand corporate-owned machines has an existing process using Jamf Pro to automate deployment of the software using this script, which no longer works on macOS 10.14 and up. The software is a client for controlling some peripherals, and is not 'hidden' -- users can see it is running and in the list of login items. I suppose an alternate solution is to direct users to add it to their login items themselves, but I imagine the client would like to leave system configuration to IT and let others do their own jobs.

Comment: What if you set up a launchagent instead?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a lot of experience administering/doing mass deployment of scripts over Jamf but I am positive the following links would be very helpful for you. I believe what you are looking for is how to work around Apple's Preferences Policy Control Payloads (PPPC).

Please take a look at the following resources:

[GitHub - homebysix](https://github.com/homebysix/tccprofile)

[Apple Official Doc about PPPC](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf)

[GitHub - Jamf](https://github.com/jamf/PPPC-Utility)

Basically, you want to figure out what you want to explicitly whitelist and preauthorize these using the MDM profile utility and deploy the profile you created along with the payload.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you’re looking for will be based around [**SMLoginItemSetEnabled()**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/servicemanagement/1501557-smloginitemsetenabled). This is the modern replacement for the deprecated `LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL()` which is used by the *Users & Groups* system preference pane.

You will need to create two small applications. The “main” application will be responsible for launching your payload. The “helper” application will be launched at login by macOS and will need to launch the “main” application. (If your payload was something you had source access to, you wouldn’t need a separate “main” application and could just add the helper directly to your app.)

There are a number of tutorials that describe this in detail. [**Here is one**.](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/01/login-items/) You can also use [**a Swift package**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/LaunchAtLogin) that contains much of the boilerplate code for you.

So here is how this would work:

1. Your automated setup script runs the main app (which also contains the helper app within its bundle) one time to set up launch at login.
2. Going forward, when the user logs in, macOS launches the helper.
3. The helper launches the main app.
4. The main app [**uses NSWorkspace to launch**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27505022/open-another-mac-app#27510973) your payload.